# assign a state value to a field in another state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have made a state `[grandTotal]` and I want to asssign the value I am getting in it to the field `grandTotal` in state `[installmentFileCategory]`

How do I assign it?

```
const [grandTotal, setgrandTotal] = useState(0);
```

```
 const [installmentFileCategory, setInstallmentFileCategory] = useState([
    {
      projectId: 0,
      phaseId: 0,
      blockId: 0,
      plotSizeId: 0,
      rate: 0,
      grandTotal: 0,
      
    },
  ]);
```

```
 <div className="col-sm-3">
     <label className="text-label">
       <b>Grand Total</b>
     </label>
     <input
        type="text"
        name="grandTotal"
        value={grandTotal}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Grand Total"
        readOnly
      />
  </div>
```

Comment: are they both in the same component?

Comment: yes they are in same component @Hasan

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is how to update an item in the state object individually:

This can be your `onChange()` handler:

```
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    // get the value from the input
    setgrandTotal(e.target.value)

    // the grandTotal state will hold the input value
    
    /* since your state object is an array, we map through the items
       in the array while preserving all the existing key-value pairs in the object.
       Then we update one item in the object with the desired value
    */
    setInstallmentFileCategory(
      installmentFileCategory.map(item =>
        {
          return {
            ...item,
            grandTotal: e.target.value,
          }
          // e.target.value holds the same value as grandTotal
        }
      )
    );

    console.log(installmentFileCategory)
  }
```

Using `onChange` however has its shortcomings since the value you expect from it won't be the realtime value, the value you get from the input will be one step behind.

You may consider using a `onKeyUp` instead so that the state object always holds realtime values.

**Check and test the code here:**

[image: Edit broken-grass-gnng7z]

Comment: grandTotal is not input filed its only read only

Comment: Same concept of the function I believe.. You just need to make your required changes and configure the above function to fire when the value of the input changex